# Suggested edit inserts a non-existent space in the output diff

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, whitespace

In this [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1235492), a whitespace character magically appeared in the rendered output diff.
The output diff contains a space before the dot, although the actual post (and markdown diff) doesn't show this character:

> I am trying to execute a simple query that inserts a timestamp . The

```
I am trying to execute a simple query that inserts a timestamp. The
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters Firefox 17, but the http response also contains the space, so I don't think that it's browser-specific.

Comment: Yeah, I misunderstood, and see the space. It's in the source. I suspect it's the differ cleaning up whitespace on the insertion a little too aggressively. The inserted text is ` into the database` (leading space), and that is not included in the shown diff; it would be difficult (involving replacing spaces with `&nbsp;` entities) to show that leading whitespace.